# Jest - mocking and testing pino multi streams based on log levels

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am struggling to find out correct way of mocking and using pino in a test logging service,
So here is my implementation of pino logger. This write to different file streams based on log levels.

```
 getChildLoggerService(fileNameString): pino.Logger {
    const streams: Streams = [
      { level: 'fatal', stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), './logs/database-connect-fatal.log'))},
      { level: 'error', stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), './logs/database-connect-error.log'))},
      { level: 'debug', stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), './logs/database-connect-debug.log'))},
      { level: 'info', stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), './logs/database-connect-info.log'))},
    ];

    return  pino({useLevelLabels: true,
      base: {
        hostName: os.hostname(),
        platform: os.platform(),
        processId: process.pid,
        timestamp: this.appUtilService.getCurrentLocaleTimeZone(),
        // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-sort-keys
        fileName: this.appUtilService.getFileName(fileNameString),
      } ,
      level: this.appUtilService.getLogLevel(),
      messageKey: LOGGER_MSG_KEY,
      prettyPrint: this.appUtilService.checkForDevEnv(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      timestamp: () => {
        return this.appUtilService.getCurrentLocaleTimeZone()
      },

    }, multistream(streams)).child({
      connectorReqId: (process.env.REQ_APP_NAME === null ? 'local': process.env.REQ_APP_NAME)
        +uuid.v4().toString()
    });
  }
```

The most important part I wanted to test is the multistreams where I need to write to different log files based on the log levels and so far I couldn't figure out a way to do that

```
import pino, { DestinationStream } from 'pino';
const sinon = require('sinon');
import pinoms from 'pino-multi-stream';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const stream = require('stream');
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');
class EchoStream extends stream.Writable {
    _write(chunk, enc, next) {
        console.log('ssdsdsd',chunk.toString());
        next();
    }
}
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Writable } from 'stream';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { LogServiceInstance } from './log.service';
// jest.mock('pino', () => jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => { ====> Tried this inline mock, doesnt work
//  return {
//      child: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(jest.requireActual('pino').Logger)
//  }
// }));
// jest.mock('pino', () => {
//  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
//      return {
//          child: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(jest.requireActual('pino').Logger),
//          stream: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
//              return [
//                  {
//                      level: 'info',
//                      stream: fs.createWriteStream(
//                          path.resolve(process.cwd(), '/test/database-connector-logs/info.log')
//                      ),
//                  },
//                  {
//                      level: 'warn',
//                      stream: fs.createWriteStream(
//                          path.resolve(process.cwd(), '/test/database-connector-logs/warn.log')
//                      ),
//                  },
//              ];
//          }),
//      };
//  });
// });



describe('Test suite for Log service', () => {
    //const mockedPino = mocked(pino, true);
    test('Test case for getLoggerInstance', () => {
        const mockedPinoMsStream = [

        const mockedPinoStream = (pino.prototype.stream = jest.fn(() => mockedPinoMsStream));

        console.dir(pino);
        const prop = Reflect.ownKeys(pino).find((s) => {
            return s === 'symbols';
        });
    // Tried this but it did not work as the actual files are written with the values
        pino[prop]['streamSym'] = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './test/database-connector-logs/info.log'))
        });
        console.dir(pino);
        const log = LogServiceInstance.getChildLoggerService(__filename);

        console.dir(Object.getPrototypeOf(log));
        log.info('test logging');
        expect(2).toEqual(2);

});
```

Could someone let me know where the mocking is wrong and how to mock it properly

**UPDATE:**

I came to understand that mocking pino-multi-stream might do the trick, so tried it this way. This was added at the very top and rest of all mockings are all removed (even inside the test suite as well)

```
const mockedPinoMultiStream  = {
    stream: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {write: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(new PassThrough())}
    })
}

jest.mock('pino-multi-stream', () => {
    return {
        multistream: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockedPinoMultiStream)
    }
});
```

wanted to mock to test if based on the level, respective named files are being used, but this also results in exception

TypeError: stream.write is not a function

```
at Pino.write (/XXX/node_modules/pino/lib/proto.js:161:15)
at Pino.LOG (/XXXX/node_modules/pino/lib/tools.js:39:26)
```

LATEST UPDATE:

So I resolved the exception by modifying the way pino multistream is mocked

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');
...
...
const mockedPinoMultiStream  = {
  write: jest.fn().mockImplementation((data) => {
   return new Passthrough();
  })
};
```

Now there is no more exception and write(method) is properly mocked when I print "pino". BUt I do not understand how to test the different files based on different log levels. Could someone let me know, how that is to be done.? 
Note: I tried setting a return value of fs.createWriteStream instead of a Passthrough but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Atlast, I found the answer to making use of pino streams based on different log levels. 
I went ahead and created a test directory to house the test log files. In reality, we do not want pino to be adulterating the actual log files. So I decided to mock the pino streams during the start of the jest test. This file gets executed first before any test suite is triggered. So I modified the jest configuration in package.json like

```
"setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest-setup/stream.logger.js"
    ],
```

in the stream.logger.js file, I added

```
const pinoms = require('pino-multi-stream');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const stream = require('stream');
const Writable = require('stream').Writable;
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');
const pino = require('pino');
class MyWritable extends Writable {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }

  _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    const writeStream =fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './test/logs/info.log'));
    writeStream.write(chunk,'utf-8');
    writeStream.emit('close');
    writeStream.end();
  }
}
const mockedPinoMultiStream  = {
  write: jest.fn().mockImplementation((data) => {
    const writeStream = new MyWritable();
    return writeStream._write(data);
  })
};
jest.mock('pino-multi-stream', () => {
    return {
        multistream: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockedPinoMultiStream)
    }
});
```

Now I went ahead and created the test file - log.service.spec.ts

```
import * as pino from 'pino';
const sinon = require('sinon');
import pinoms from 'pino-multi-stream';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const stream = require('stream');


import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Writable } from 'stream';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { LogServiceInstance } from './log.service';

describe('Test suite for Log service', () => {
    //const mockedPino = mocked(pino, true);
    afterEach(() => {
        // delete the contents of the log files after each test suite
        fs.truncate((path.resolve(process.cwd(), './test/logs/info.log')), 0, () => {
            console.dir('Info log file deleted');
        });

        fs.truncate((path.resolve(process.cwd(), './test/logs/warn.log')), 0, () => {
            console.dir('Warn log file deleted');
        });
        fs.truncate((path.resolve(process.cwd(), './test/logs/debug.log')), 0, () => {
            console.dir('Debug log file deleted');
        });
    });
    test('Test case fir getLoggerInstance', () => {
        const pinoLoggerInstance = LogServiceInstance.getChildLoggerService(__filename);
        pinoLoggerInstance.info('test logging');

        _.map(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(pinoLoggerInstance), (mapItems:any) => {
            if(mapItems.toString().includes('Symbol')) {
                if(mapItems.toString().includes('pino.level')) {
                    expect(pinoLoggerInstance[mapItems]).toEqual(20);
                }
            }
            if(mapItems.toString().includes('pino.chindings')) {
                const childInstance = pinoLoggerInstance[mapItems].toString().substr(1);
                const jsonString  = '{'+ childInstance+ '}';
                const expectedObj = Object.create(JSON.parse(jsonString));
                expect(expectedObj.fileName).toEqual('log.service.spec');
                expect(expectedObj.appName).toEqual('AppJestTesting');
                expect(expectedObj.connectorReqId).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(new String('AppJestTesting')));
            }
        });
        // make sure the info.log file is written in this case
        const infoBuffRead = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './test/logs/info.log')).read(1024);
        expect(infoBuffRead).toBeDefined();

        // now write a warn log
        pinoLoggerInstance.warn('test warning log');
        const warnBuffRead = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './test/logs/warn.log')).read(1024);
        expect(warnBuffRead).toBeDefined();


        // now write a debug log
        pinoLoggerInstance.debug('test warning log');
        const debugBuffRead = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './test/logs/warn.log')).read(1024);
        expect(debugBuffRead).toBeDefined();


    });
});
```

I also made sure that the test log files do not get overwhelmed with data over time , by deleting their contents after each execution
Hope this helps people trying to test pino multi stream